# G1ANT Studio Watson Addon

Tags: g1ant

The **watson.classifyimage** command is not working in the watson addon. Reason seems to be an incorrect api key.

The error message displays connection error. Anyone else facing a similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

Alright. So I found the solution to run the command successfully.

Follow these steps:

1. Create a free account on [https://cloud.ibm.com/registration][1]
2. Go to the Catalog and Add the visual recognition service
3. After adding the service click on credentials on the service details page.
4. Click on add credentials
5. Follow through the process and generate a new credential with a default name of service credential 1.
6. copy the credentials from the option provided in the same row.
7. paste the credential details in notepad and then extract the api key from it.
8. keeping the rest of the code same, (not changing the url) use the api key in your code and the program should work just fine.

Same steps can be followed for the speech-to-text command as well. Also, you can use the auto generated credentials too for extracting the api key.

Hope this helps!